# Create a MySQL connection in Playframework with slick

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, slick

I'm trying to connect to a mysql database with slick 1.0.0.

What I've done so far:

in Build.scala I've added

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    anorm,
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.24",
    "com.typesafe.slick" % "slick_2.10" % "1.0.0",
    "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4"
)
```

in application.conf

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="url to mysql db"
db.default.user=user
db.default.pass=password
```

and now I'm trying to read an Entry from the DB. For this I have a model

```
package models

import scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple._
import Database.threadLocalSession

object Organisations extends Table[(Int, String)]("Organisation")
{
    def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
    def name = column[String]("name")
    def * = id ~ name
}
```

and now I'd like to just output the entries

```
val orgs =
    for { o <- Organisations } yield o.name

println("Length" + orgs.toString())
```

But it doesn't work. I'm sure I've made plenty of errors, but there don't seem to be andy slick tutorials with mysql.

Thank you for your patience and I hope my explanations are clear.

Comment: Can you qualify "doesn't work"?  What kinds of unexpected behaviors or exceptions are you seeing?

Comment: thank you for answering.

the problem was all that boilerplate that @johanandren talks about.
I didn't know how to tell slick to use my config file and all that. With the plugin it works now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Slick requires a bit of boilerplate, creating session and all that, checkout the Play-Slick plugin written by Fredrik Ekholdt (typesafe)!

It does all that plumbing for you and there are good examples on the wiki on how to use it.

https://github.com/freekh/play-slick/

Comment: thank you very much :)

It works great.

Now I just have to figure out the details.

You're great!

Comment: am I the only one to be a little concerned by this? https://www.dropbox.com/s/6vakhhlik4msy1o/Screenshot%202015-10-21%2016.18.48.png?dl=0

I find all things Play Framework to be quite poorly documented.

Answer (score 2):

The new Slick 2.0 also features a Code Generator that can be used together with Play Framework evolutions.

This means you **don't have to write the boilerplate for Slick anymore**. Just write your database changes using evolutions files, and immediately access the new tables from your code.

You can find a complete example using MySQL here:

https://github.com/papauschek/play-slick-evolutions

And more information on how it works:

http://blog.papauschek.com/2013/12/slick-2-0-code-generator-play-framework-evolutions/

Comment: thank you, I will look at it next time I write a play application. (Will be in a month or two)

Comment: I am using this method in a new project now, and after a day of getting it to work it's great now.

Answer (score 1):

The Play team have also been working on a slick benchmark for Techempower. It is a work in progress but we'll shortly be raising a PR on the completed version (next 24 hours I suspect):

https://github.com/nraychaudhuri/FrameworkBenchmarks/tree/adding_missing_slickness/play-slick

Comment: you mean to use as reference?
Thank you. I didn't know about the list method of the result.