# Mysql play-slick connection timeout error

Tags: mysql, playframework, play-slick

Possible duplicate: [Create a MySQL connection in Playframework with slick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569050/create-a-mysql-connection-in-playframework-with-slick?rq=1)

I am using play-slick plugin to try connecting with mysql database. But I get connection timeout error every time slick tries to communicate with the Db. My application.conf file is as follow:

```
slick.dbs.default.driver= "slick.driver.MySQLDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DatabaseUrlDataSource"
slick.dbs.default.db.properties.driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306"
slick.dbs.default.db.username="root"
slick.dbs.default.db.password="xxxx"
slick.dbs.default.db.connectionTimeout=15s
slick.dbs.default.db.numThreads = 12
slick.dbs.default.db.connectionTestQuery="select 1"
```

And whenever my application tries to communicate with the database it gets this error:

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[SQLTimeoutException: Timeout after 15001ms of waiting for a connection.]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:265) ~[play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
```

I have checked that mysql is listening on port 3306. There is a service mysqld that's running. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Change *slick.dbs.default.db.username* to *slick.dbs.default.db.user*.

Hikari connection pool logs wrong username login attempts only in *DEBUG* level, otherwise fails with timeout silently.

Try setting *com.zaxxer.hikari* to *DEBUG* in logback.xml to see the errors.

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful to somebody who stumbles with a similar timeout error:

```
[SQLTransientConnectionException: db - Connection is not available, request timed out after 1000ms.]
```

Following what @Kairius said, i enabled com.zaxxer.hikari logging in my logback.xml file:

```
<logger name="com.zaxxer.hikari" level="DEBUG" />
```

I got the following error when play-slick evolutions tried to make a connection on my app start up (one of many):

```
java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'COT' is unrecognized or
represents more than one time zone.
```

And i fixed that by adding `?serverTimezone=UTC` into my connection string, like so:

```
 slick.dbs.default {
  profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
  db {
    driver = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eventos?serverTimezone=UTC"
    user =root
    password =root
  }
}
```

Im using MySQL 8.0.13 and these are my sbt dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "3.0.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "3.0.1"
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "8.0.13"
```